# Send securestring to function in a powershell module

Tags: powershell, securestring

i have a function in a Powershell module which should establish a database session with SimplySql. SimplySql takes a credential object. Now i have several problems, to send the password into the function. What i tried:

1. When using a [string]$password parameter i get the warning `"Parameter '$password' should use SecureString, otherwise this will expose sensitive information"`. Makes absolute sense, so i changed the param to securestring.
2. I created the secure string with `"$SecurePassword = "myPassword" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force"`, imported the module again and called the function. Now i get the following message: `Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Password'. Cannot convert the "System.Security.SecureString" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Security.SecureString"`. I checked the SecureString with `$myLocalSecString.GetType()`, and "yes" its a Secure String.
3. Because i didn't found any solution for that, i tried to set `[PSCredential]$cred` as input object. I created the object with `[pscredential]$_credObject = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("myusername", $SecurePassword)`. When i call the function now, i get the following message:

> ```
> PowerShell credential request
> Enter your credentials.
> Password for user System.Management.Automation.PSCredential:
> ```

I think i created the SecureString on a wrong way in scenario 2 and 3, but i didn't what i doing wrong. The script should work on Powershell Core.

Would be great to get a good hint here.

Thanks in advance

Dave

Comment: "SimplySql takes a credential object" - can you elaborate on this? If the target module accepts a `[pscredential]`, then the best thing you can do is to accept one as well and pass it on to the module as-is, never touch the plaintext password

Comment: Yes, SImplySql takes an credential object. I tried to create this and give that to my function as describes above (Bullet number 3). But then i get a prompt to enter my password manual.

Comment: Can you please show the full script that creates the credential object an calls the script/function? There must be something missing

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay, had vacation ;-). 
@Ma

Answer (score 1):

sorry for the delay, had vacation ;-).
I tried it again now to provide you with a complete code sample. I don't what i changed, but know its working.
I was really sure, that i created it with

```
$_secString = ConvertTo-SecureString "test" -AsPlainText -Force
[pscredential]$_credObject = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("mydbuser", $_secString)
```

the last time. I did it with the same command today and it works. Strange. Mea culpa to stole your time....

Really strange.